# Me sale este error en vercel 404: NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api

**Este seria mi Index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const meals = require("./routes/meals");
const orders = require("./routes/orders");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
app.use("api/meals", meals);

module.exports = app;
```

404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND
ID: dev1::k97jp-1638276573418-33ed55c88db6
cuando ejecuto , voy a la direccion y me dirige a la direccion de arriba con ese error 404:NOT_FOUND

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: si nose como editarlo